# Solidity initialize memory array of fixed size

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, arrays, error

Using solidity 0.4.15, there is a function that takes a number and returns array of fixed length called `traits`:

```
function splitN(uint256 n) constant returns (uint8[12]) {
    uint8[12] memory traits = new uint8[12];
    // alter values in traits ...
    return traits;
}
```

But this way to initialize `traits` don't compile, with the errors:

```
.../Genes.sol:28:39: TypeError: Length has to be placed in parentheses after the array type for new expression.
        uint8[12] memory traits = new uint8[12];
                                      ^-------^
,.../Genes.sol:28:9: TypeError: Type function (uint256) returns (uint8[12] memory) is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint8[12] memory.
        uint8[12] memory traits = new uint8[12];
```

Then I tried following the message hints, and a bunch of other ways to initialize, but the only way I could make it work was to actually fill an array of 12 zeroes:

```
    uint8 z = 0;
    uint8[12] memory traits = [z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z];
```

So is there a more elegant way of initializing the array?

Comment: did you try just `uint8[12] memory traits;` ?

Comment: You are right @AchalaDissanayake ! Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To initialize an empty array  instead of `uint8[12] memory traits = new uint8[12];` use `uint8[12] memory traits;`.

Then you can alter the array  in the `// alter values in traits ...` section.

```
function splitN(uint256 n) constant returns (uint8[12]) {
    uint8[12] memory traits;
    // alter values in traits ...
    return traits;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In order to initialize an array from memory you have to do it like this:

```
uint8[] memory theArray = new uint8[](12)
```

Where the 12 inside the parenthesis is the array length.

You can also initialize the array as follows:

```
function getTraits() constant returns (uint8[3]){
      uint8[3] memory traits = [1,2,3];
      return traits;
    }
```

Comment: My question is to init `uint8[12]`, this solution errors to return: `TypeError: Return argument type uint8[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) uint8[12] memory.
        return traits;`

Comment: You have to change the function's return type to uint8[] to fix that.
Alternatively, you could initialize de fixed-size array like I just wrote in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to initialize a fixed-size memory array. In solidity docs, it says we need to use "new" operator. But actually, here is how I did without "new" operator (second way). Also another bonus, I added return statements for both ways.

```
    // Way 1: by using the "new" operator
    function createArr1(uint _n, uint _m, uint _k) external pure returns(uint[] memory) {
        uint[] memory a = new uint[](3);
        a[0] = _n;
        a[1] = _m;
        a[2] = _k;
        return a;
    }
    // Way 2: without "new" operator.
    function createArr2(uint _n, uint _m, uint _k) external pure returns(uint[3] memory) {
        uint[3] memory a = [_n, _m, _k];
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax if you don't know the correct value and initialize using a variable.

```
function abc(uint[] a) public {
    uint[] memory c = new uint[](a.length);
}
```